# CreateProcess doesn't run .cmd file after converting project to support Unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, process, mfc

I have changed an old MFC application to support Unicode. Now the code looks as follows. Basically I'm calling a .cmd file here:

```
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
DWORD dwErrorCode;

PROCESS_INFORMATION * processInformation = new PROCESS_INFORMATION[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    GetStartupInfo(&StartupInfo);

    if (processList[i].bHide)
    {
        StartupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    }

    if (processList[i].sCustomTitle.GetLength())
        StartupInfo.lpTitle = processList[i].sCustomTitle.GetBuffer(processList[i].sCustomTitle.GetLength());

    CreateProcess(NULL, 
        /*I changed LPSTR to LPWSTR*/(LPWSTR)(LPCTSTR)processList[i].sCommandLine,
        NULL, NULL, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &processInformation[i]);

    [...]
}
```

The only change I did was changing `LPSTR` to `LPWSTR`. Before converting to Unicode this was working without any issue. But now it is not running. What could be the reason? Did I miss anything that needs to be done when converting to `Unicode` support?

P.S.: I debugged and checked all the parameters. They look fine. `sCommandLine` is a `CString` variable in the `PROCESS_STARTUP_INFO struct`.

Comment: Get rid of the casts.  "Converting to Unicode support" requires converting, not casting.

Comment: @BenVoigt you mean just use processList[i].sCommandLine rather than (LPWSTR)(LPCTSTR)processList[i].sCommandLine ?

Comment: You must pass a pointer to NUL-terminated Unicode string.  You cannot create a Unicode string by casting.  What data type is `sCommandLine`?

Comment: @BenVoigt It is a CString, So I think I must cast it.

Comment: CString has an implicit conversion, you shouldn't ever write a cast (exception: variadic functions like `printf`... but even then a temporary variable is better)

Comment: I suggest you read http://www.flounder.com/cstring.htm#Unicode%20and%20CStrings

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for link. I will look in to that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59783/discussion-between-thusitha-thilina-dayaratne-and-ben-voigt).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you should not cast your string. You should use a temporary variable, because of the following remark in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

Recently I had a similar problem. I solved it the following way (I tried to make it bullet-proof):

```
// The maximum length of the command line string is 32,768 characters,
// including the Unicode terminating null character.
#define MAX_CMD_LINE_LEN 32768

// Use a temporary variable for the command line.
TCHAR szCmdLine[MAX_CMD_LINE_LENGTH];

// Get the length of the command line. Crop the command line if it is too long.
int iLen = min(processList[i].sCommandLine.GetLength(), MAX_CMD_LINE_LEN - 1);

// Copy the command line string to the temporary variable.
_tcsncpy_s(szCmdLine, processList[i].sCommandLine, iLen);

// Create the process by passing the temporary variable holding a copy of your
// original command line string.
CreateProcess(NULL, 
              szCmdLine,
              NULL, NULL, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL,
              NULL, &StartupInfo, &processInformation[i]);
```

This solution should compile and work for Unicode and non-Unicode builds.